# Does the limit for this composite function exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm brushing up on my calculus, and I happened upon a confusing edge case. Khan Academy showed me this question:

> Find $\lim_{x\to 3}g(f(x))$
>   [image]

Now, my intuition tells me that as $x$ approaches $3$, $f(x)$ approaches $-1$ and is always larger than $-1$. So as $f(x)$ approaches $-1$, $g(f(x))$ then approaches $0$. As $f(x)$ never actually becomes $-1$, it should not matter that $g(x)$ is not defined for $x = -1$.

However, Khan Academy and several other sites I've found teaches the rule that $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))$. Using this rule, if $g(L)$ is undefined for $L = \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, then the limit is undefined. So for the question I was given, the limit does not exist because $g(-1)$ is undefined.

This does not make sense to me. Can someone explain to me if and how my intuition is wrong, or if the rule $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x)) = g(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))$ is inaccurate?

Comment: That rule requires $g$ to be continuous.

Comment: You are correct that $g(f(x)) \to g(-1+) = 0$.